# Is there a structure in Python similar to C++ STL map?

Tags: c++, python

Is there a structure in `Python` which supports similar operations to `C++ STL map` and complexity of operations correspond to `C++ STL map`?

Comment: Have you checked out ordered dictionaries in Python 3.1?

Comment: Looking into them. Thanks, that should be enough for my purpose. The hash insertion/deletion is O(1), but I guess that would require more memory than tree with O(logN).

Comment: Trees and hash tables both require O(n) memory.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`dict` is usually close enough - what do you want that it doesn't do?

If the answer is "provide order", then what's actually wrong with `for k in sorted(d.keys())`? Uses too much memory, maybe? If you're doing lots of ordered traversals interspersed with inserts then OK, point taken, you really do want a tree.

`dict` is actually a hash table rather than a b-tree. But then `map` isn't *defined* to be a b-tree, so it doesn't let you do things like detaching sub-trees as a new `map`, it just has the same performance complexities. All that's really left to worry about is what happens to `dict` when there are large numbers of hash collisions, but it must be pretty rare to use Python in situations where you want tight worst-case performance guarantees.

Comment: Yea, dict should be enough. Thanks!

Comment: `dict` doesn't provide equivalent for `map::lower_bound`, so I can't search for the closest element to a known key in a `dict`.

Comment: @lvella: yes, that's part of "provide order" (although the thing called "ordered container" in C++ is usually called "sorted container" in Python). If you need a sorted container then it's either a library or (for learning purposes) hit the textbooks and roll your own.

Comment: There is an important use case NOT covered by python dict. Namely for two elements comparing equal `stl map` will contain only one of them, that is `map` glues them together. Case where you'd want to use that is for example if you want to cache the results of function calls on some objects. Different objects hash differently but we'd want a single entry for arguments that should give the same value.
Python `dict` being a hashmap is not meant for this usage.

Comment: @zaabson: if `hash()` is implemented correctly for the type, then in Python `x == y` implies `hash(x) == hash(y)`, and so `dict` behaves the same way as C++ `map` does for equal keys: you only get one entry in the dictionary. If `hash()` is implemented incorrectly then you're in trouble, much as you would be with C++ `map` if you tried to use a type whose `operator<` was inconsistent with `operator==`, or with C++ `unordered_map` and an incorrect hash implemention.

Answer (score 17):

Python SortedDict is a similar to C++ STL map. You can read about it [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sortedcontainers) or [here](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/index.html).

> SortedDict is a container of key-value pairs in which an order is
>   imposed on the keys according to their ordered relation to each other.
>   As with Python’s built-in dict data type, SortedDict supports fast
>   insertion, deletion, and lookup by key.

Comment: When googling this, be careful to not use what Django calls `SortedDict`, because that one is more like `OrderedDict`, which preserves insertion order instead of key order.

Answer (score 9):

I believe that the standard python type dict() will do the trick in most cases. The difference from C++'s std::map is that dict is impemented as a hash map and C++'s map is tree-based.

Answer (score 1):

Python [dictionaries [5.5]](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping).

Answer (score 1):

Look at bintrees module (pip install bintrees). This package provides Binary- RedBlack- and AVL-Trees written in Python and Cython/C.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Python dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the python dictionary dict() will work just fine similar to stl map of C++ because they both are implemented using a hash table.
Please look at [python_dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)

Answer (score -1):

use this : from sortedcontainers import SortedDict

don't use this: from collections import OrderedDict